# Errors from wcf service method after few hours of work

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I have a problem with wcf servcices. 
Wcf services method is inovked by an application. This app calls service method very often (dozens of times per minute). The service method is called properly (with Close() at the end, or Abort() after exception). The most strange thing for me is that after few hours my app is getting errors from services:

*An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://domain.xx/MyService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.*

or this one:

**The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:15:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. The HTTP request to 'http://domain.xx/MyService.svc' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:15:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. The operation has timed out **

What can couse such errors? Why services are working properly within few first hours?

Comment: perhaps you are calling this method in question recursively post sample of your code..

Answer (score 1):

I would check your application log.  From my experience, those errors tend to me more server related than code related.  IIS may be having problems.

Comment: Good call, try using SvcTraceTool http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx to analize your logs

Answer (score 0):

I know you mentioned it but it looks your are not closing your channels right. Also, make sure you do NOT use the same client for many server calls. Just create one, use it for a single call, and dispose it.

Here's a [good read](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2009/06/26/disposing-a-wcf-proxy.aspx) about closing WCF channels.